# Facebook Graph API object cannot be loaded due to missing permissions

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Helo.
We use Facebook Graph API with PHP to retrieve events from Facebook pages. We use latest PHP SDK for that purpose.
We succesfully get information from most of the pages, but from several of them we get error:
Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
Error code: 100.
We can not find any explanation of this error in FB API documentation.
We notice that it usually happens when the page we try to access has alcohol promotion.
Does anybody has any idea?
Thanks in advance for Your help.
Here's the real PHP code we use:

```
require_once ('../fbsdk.v5/src/Facebook/autoload.php');<br />
session_start();<br />
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
    'app_id'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'app_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    )),
    $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$fbApp = $fb->getApp();
$params = array(
    'fields' => 'events'
);
$fbReq = new Facebook\FacebookRequest($fbApp, $token, 'GET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', $params);
try {
    $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($fbReq);
    $events = $response->getDecodedBody();
    $events = $events['events']['data'];
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    echo '. Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Probably the page owner set the-event-privacy-set not open.

Comment: Hi. It's not for one event alone. We get this error when we try to get info from whole page.

Comment: Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page#Reading) for page permission. Notes on the restricted field (i.e alcohol content, etc)